# conditional gdb breakpoint after getting the char* from an function

Tags: c++, gdb

**Skeleton code:**

Let us say you have something like this(x.cpp):

```
int main() {
   char* str = <some_function_which_returns_char*>; // Such as hello, hell, hellow and it could be anything.
   // Do some work here.
}
```

How do you put a breakpoint in gdb if str contains "hell". This substr 'hell' can come at any location of str. Say ahell, hello etc. I have written:

```
b x.cpp:3 if $_regex(str, "hell") // At line number 3 of above snapshot. Right after getting the char*
```

Is it the right way?
OR
Are there any other ways to deal with it?

Let us not worry about the leaks and anything else for now.

Comment: see https://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf

Comment: @alon, Thanks for your reply. What about it though? I already have it. :) Does not have these tiny details.

Comment: Can you not use `break/watch <where> if <condition>`, in the condition you can compare the first character to 'h' && the second to 'e' && ....

Comment: @Mansoor, Well, there should be better solutions to it instead of comparing it manually. What would you do if the string it large?

Comment: cond x.cpp:3 strcmp(str,"hell") == 0
//stop if the array str is equal to 'hell'  
 see example https://www.fayewilliams.com/2011/07/13/gdb-conditional-breakpoints/

Comment: @alon, Thanks. I want to make it stop for hello or hellow or helll as well. Basically which have substring as hell.

Comment: do strncmp (str,"hell",4)

Comment: @alon, Thanks. May be my question is not clear. What if hell comes in the end. Say ahell.

Comment: You search for something like `if strstr(str, "hell") != NULL` right?

Comment: yes strtsr  that @Kamil Cuk  suggested will work if you need to find substring in a string

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cond` command to make the breakpoint conditional:

- `cond x.cpp:3 strcmp(str,"hell") == 0` - for `hell` exactly.
- `cond x.cpp:3 strncmp (str,"hell",4)` - for all strings that start with `hell`.
- `cond x.cpp:3 strstr(str, "hell") != NULL` - for all strings containing `hell` as a substring.